# Why unique_ptr's Deleter need an argument of type unique_ptr<T, Deleter>::pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, std

I see the describtion  about `unique_ptr` on cppreference, it says  `Deleter must be FunctionObject or lvalue reference to a FunctionObject or lvalue reference to function, callable with an argument of type unique_ptr<T, Deleter>::pointer`, I don't understand why there is such a requirement that
FunctionObject  must have an argument   and if I want  to implement  the requirement,How shoud I do?

Comment: you dont have to supply a deleter, the default one works fine. I have never provided a deleter in all the time i used shared and unique_ptr

Comment: Sometimes I may use the deleter to  guard something,  I think it is useful.I cant understand Why the deleter must need  argument.

Comment: the argument passed to the deleter is the object to delete

Comment: OK,I understand , very thanks

Comment: there is an example on the page you quote, customer deleter called 'close_file' https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

Comment: Yeah,I see, thanks, I know how to write a deleter.  Maybe the deleter is born for T( unique_ptr<T, Deleter>),So  the argument is 
 a must

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That requirement is expressing that `unique_ptr` more or less looks like this:

```
class unique_ptr {
    pointer ptr;
    [[no_unique_address]] deleter_type del;
public:
    /* other members */
    ~unique_ptr() { del(ptr); } 
};
```

That is, it ensures that the pointed-to value is "freed" when the pointer is destroyed, whatever "freed" means.

`std::default_delete` is similarly more or less:

```
struct default_delete {
    void operator()(pointer ptr) const { delete ptr; }
};
```

So if you want to write a custom deleter, it should have a member function `void operator()(pointer ptr) const`, in which you do whatever cleanup.